Enforcing TLS 1.2+ on GTM Server-Side Tagging Server (App Engine)
I have set up a Google Tag Manager (GTM) server-side tagging server for one of my clients. The tagging server uses the domain tagging.example.com, while the client's primary domain is www.example.com. This setup has been running smoothly for over a year.
Recently, the client's IT team updated their security policy to only allow TLS connections that are equal to or greater than TLS 1.2. However, the tagging server (tagging.example.com) is still allowing connections with TLS versions lower than 1.2. This is raising concerns about potential security vulnerabilities, and the client’s IT team has requested that we resolve this issue as soon as possible.
Could someone please guide me on how to ensure that the GTM server-side tagging server only allows TLS 1.2 or higher? I appreciate any insights or solutions on how to implement this in the current setup.
Thanks in advance!
